# How do you visiaulize dataframe in foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

Im following this demo https://github.com/IBM/example-health-machine-learning/blob/master/diabetes-prediction.ipynb

Here it says to use pixiedust to visualize the dataset, not sure how to do it with codeworkbooks or code repo. any suggestion

Tried in Codeworkbook, but got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unnamed_3", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pixiedust/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pixiedust.utils.pdLogging as pdLogging
  File "/opt/spark/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pixiedust/utils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    storage._initStorage()
  File "/opt/spark/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pixiedust/utils/storage.py", line 68, in _initStorage
    _conn = sqlite3.connect(SQLITE_DB_NAME_PATH)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple checks you have to consider in order to use code workbook for visualization same as jupyternotebook.

1. Select the correct input type. In order to use standard python libraries like Matlplotlib, seaborn or plotly..etc your input should be always python dataframe
   [Select correct input format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkX4M.png)
2. Configure your environment by importing all the libraries that you want to use.
3. You can simply import pixiedust library from ENVIRONMENT CONFIGURATION which is available on top right on code workbook.
   [How to configure environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra34y.png)
4. There is also an error shows on your end regarding unable to open database file so make sure first of all you have input ready in the form of foundry dataset.
   https://velvet.palantirfoundry.com/docs/foundry/code-workbook/transforms-visualize

Note: Code repository does not have capability for visualization